# SSMS import latest file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I need to import a file using SQL Server Import and Export wizard. I will be saving this import as an SSIS package for execution later on. My issue is that the end of the file name will change each time and I need to load the latest one. See picture below. How do I make my filename dynamic (something like Survey_*.csv syntax exists?) and how do I pick up the latest file?

[image]

Comment: The wizard alone can't do this.  You'll need to edit your SSIS package to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the file name for your file connection to a variable, then you can set that at run time using a Script Task. This will require some programming in either C# or VB.NET. The code for this sort of thing isn't usually too difficult though, and with a little Google or StackOverflow you should be able to handle most requirements pretty easily. How you set the file name will depend on your specific requirements - do you always want to just create the file name as `Filename_YYYYMMDD.csv` for the current date? Do you want to look in a directory to get the latest file and use that? Just make sure that you have a mechanism in place to prevent processing a file twice. Personally, I always have an Archive folder and I move processed files into that folder once they are done so that my ETL can always just pick up new files from the working directory without worrying about duplicate processing.

To set the file to use the variable file name:

1. Open up the Connection Manager for the file
2. Click on the ellipses button next to Expressions
3. Select the ConnectionString property from the drop down box of a new property expression row
4. Open up the Expression Builder using the ellipses button next to the Expression cell for that property
5. Select your variable. The expression should end up in the form: `@[User::variablename]`
6. Click OK for each of the dialogs